# Dual boot PC using Intel RST Raid

Tags: dual-boot, raid, mdadm

Has anyone been successful accessing (read and write) an Intel RST raid array from both Windows and Ubuntu on a dual boot PC?  I have a single PC with 6 drives:

1. Ubuntu O/S  (m2)
2. Windows O/S (SSD)
3. 4 member Raid 5 array (HDD) with data on it.  Formatted in NTFS.

I am wanting to build a raid 5 array of the 4 data drives that I can access from both Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.10 depending on which O/S I boot at the time.  I was trying to use the motherboard RST in Windows and mdadm in Ubuntu, but have not been successful.

I started with building the RST array in Windows and was able to do that successfully.  But when I mount that using mdadm in Ubunutu, it does not recognize the meta data.

If someone has has a shared raid 5 array using another mechanism, I would be interested in how they did that too.

I am not wanting to purchase a h/w raid controller.

I have logged a support ticket with Intel. They initially replied that there is a driver issue when sharing between the two O/S.  But when I sent them an Intel document that makes it appear to be possible, they asked for time to research further.  Why I wait for their reply, I thought I would ask here.

So I just wanted to see if anyone was able to share a raid 5 array in a dual boot PC?  Or if anyone has a different mechanism.  I prefer Ubuntu mdraid (without RST) as that allows me to add/change storage overtime.  But I don't see a way to access an mdadm raid set when booted in windows.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This question reads like it was written for a forum (*this is a Q&A site & not a forum, https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the Ubuntu Forums site*) with no clear question & asking for suggestions? *Opinions* or *subjective* questions are off-topic on this site (*Forums are better suited for those questions than a Q&A site*)  I suggest you read https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask and maybe even https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  We all strive for a quality community.  The first line of my post was an attempt at a direct question.  Social troubleshooting is new to me.  I worked 35 years in tech industry, but I have not used the social forums until I started this home Ubuntu project.  I appreciate the guiance.

Answer (score 0):

I heard back from Intel support:

> We apologize for the misunderstanding, basically, the RAID
> configuration through the Intel(R) Rapid Storage Technology software
> cannot be done with a dual-boot system. If you need to configure a
> dual-boot system, you will need to complete the process through the
> motherboard BIOS, and the support is provided by the motherboard
> manufacturer.

Since the motherboard manufacture (MSI) only provides support for Windows, it is not possible to dual boot and access the raid set via Ubuntu and Linux.

Posting that answer here for others who are researching the topic.